# Approach the value through derivative

Tags: calculus

We have the function $y=50-x^2$.
We are asked to calculate approximately the change that $y$ will undergo when $x$ increases from $2$ to $4$. We are mainly asked to use the expression dy=y'(x)*dx.

What I did was to calculate $y'(x) =-2x$ thus $y'(2)=-4$ and then:
$dy=y'(2)(4-2)=-4\cdot(4-2)=-8$

So the answer is that through the differential of the function we found that finally $y$ decreases by $8$, when $x$ increases from $2$ to $4$. Is my way of thinking correct?

I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't get the question. $\left(50-4^2\right)-\left(50-2^2\right)=-12$

Answer (score 1):

Your way of thinking is correct. But the approximation becomes better (in this case it is even exact) if you use $y'$ for the *midpoint* of the change rather than the starting point. Which is to say, $y'(3)$ instead of $y'(2)$.